# File Format to Write out map data

Tags: java, hashmap, java-io, file-format

I want to write out the hashmap in java, having Key:String and Value:List<UserInfo>.
The UserInfo object has (id, name, category, type) vaues.

Can someone suggest the file format to writeout the map data, which is easy to read.
I wrote in csv file, but have to write key for each object of list, that doesn't look good.

I'm beginner in file reading and writing in java.

Comment: I would recommend to write the data in JSON.

Comment: JSON, XML, YAML, take your pick.